# Mean width of intersection of two elipsoid

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, mg.metric-geometry, convex-analysis, measure-concentration

My question is regarding mean widths. For a set $\mathcal{T}$ define the mean width

\begin{align*}
\omega(T)=\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{g}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\mathbf{I})}\bigg[\underset{\mathbf{u}\in\mathcal{T}}{\sup}\text{ } \mathbf{u}^T\mathbf{g}\bigg].
\end{align*}

My question is what is the mean width of two ellipsoid i.e. mean width of the following set 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{T}_1\cap\mathcal{T}_2
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{T}_1=\{\mathbf{A}_1\mathbf{u}| \|\mathbf{u}\|_{\ell_2}\le 1\}\quad\text{and}\quad \mathcal{T}_2=\{\mathbf{A}_2\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{c}|\|\mathbf{u}\|_{\ell_2}\le 1\}
\end{align*}
I'm interested in a good upperbound on $\omega(\mathcal{T})$.

Comment: Trivial upper-bound is $\omega(T) \le \min(\omega(T_1),\omega(T_2))$.